# How to require iuplua module from another folder?

Tags: lua, iup

I have a simple `test.lua` script that creates a window using iuplua. I call it with `lua C:\path\to\test.lua`. If I call it from `C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua` where all the iup libraries at, everything is fine no matter where the script itself is placed. The line from command prompt looks like that:

```
C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua>lua C:\Users\username\Desktop\test.lua
```

But if I call it from any other directory but iuplua I get such error:

```
C:\Users\username\Desktop>lua test.lua
lua: error loading module 'iuplua' from file 'C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua\Lua54\iuplua54.dll':
        The specified module could not be found.
```

LUA_PATH:

```
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\lua\?.lua
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\lua\?\init.lua
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\?.lua
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\?\init.lua
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\..\share\lua\5.4\?.lua
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\..\share\lua\5.4\?\init.lua
.\?.lua
.\?\init.lua
```

LUA_CPATH:

```
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\?.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\..\lib\lua\5.4\?.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\loadall.dll
.\?.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua\Lua54\?54.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua\Lua54\?.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua\?54.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\iuplua\?.dll
```

Last 4 lines in LUA_CPATH are added by me, but if I put `package.cpath = package.cpath..";these 4 lines"` at the beginning of the script the result is the same.

OS is Windows 10, Lua version is 5.4.4, IUP version is 3.30, I didn't build it but downloaded binaries and Lua bindings from SourceForge: `iup-3.30_Win64_dll16_lib` and `iup-3.30-Lua54_Win64_dll16_lib`.

Can I do something to be able to launch lua not from iuplua folder but from everywhere I want?

Comment: Your `package.path` looks non-standard.

Comment: @ESkri I'm not sure about it... May be it was modified by luarocks somehow during installation... I tried to remove LUA_PATH from system variables entirely, it didn't change anything. And if I remove LUA_CPATH, then my code stops working whatsoever with `lua: test.lua:1: module 'iuplua' not found:  no field package.preload['iuplua']`. I added my variables to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually, I just dropped all the dlls into `bin` folder with `lua.exe` and `lua54.dll`. Added following paths to my `LUA_CPATH` system variable:

```
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\?.dll
C:\lua-5.4.4\bin\?54.dll
```

As much as I don't like having all IUPLua binaries in the same folder with Lua binaries, it seems it's the only way to do it.

Also, I can require `iuplua` in the modern way like that: `local anyname = require 'iuplua'`, but all other modules like `iupluacontrols` or `iuplua_plot` must be called in the old way: `require 'iupluacontrols'` and `require 'iuplua_plot'`. Then all functions from loaded modules are available in `anyname` table.

Answer (score 1):

In short, when `require'iuplua'`, lua will try to open the `luaopen_iuplua` function in the file.

If the loading method is changed to `require'iup.iuplua'`, it will try to open the `luaopen_iup_iuplua` function in the file, which does not exist in the file, so it will error

One solution is to add a line of statement before executing the require: `package.cpath = package.cpath .. 'iup/?.dll'`

Another option is to open the DLL with `package.loadlib('iup/iuplua.dll', 'luaopen_iuplua')`.